# How to talk about people you know?

Tags: meaning

In French the word I'd use is *mes connaissances*. But this word also (and mainly) means *the things I know*, and then the traduction I find is: *my knowledges*.

Is this double meaning exists in English and what should I say to talk about people I know and who know me without being my friends?

Edit (an example of context):

> This software is very popular, if you have any problem with it just ask to your **connaissances**, I think that somebody could help you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *my knowledges*. Also, what you want to ask? You want to refer people whom you know?

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, but not necessarily my friends.

Comment: the word is acquaintances.

Comment: Can you share an example sentence? And exactly who are these people? I ask because "acquaintance" sounds very formal, and depending on the context there may be a better phrasing -- for instance, a word that describes how you know them (colleagues, for instance.)

Comment: @relaxing I just add an exemple. In my mind **les connaissances** contains the family, friends, colleagues, neighbours, your sport team, and maybe many other **connaissances** ; )

Comment: I wouldn't use acquaintance there. It makes sense, but wouldn't be used in everyday speech. You could definitely use "friend", as you'd have to be on somewhat friendly terms with someone to bug them with software questions :)  I would use "someone/somebody" and let the reader infer "someone you know." Or if you have a specific audience, say "colleague/classmate/etc..."  My phrasing: "This software is very popular. If you have any problems with it, just ask someone for help."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I typed and translated *mes connaissances* in Google, it showed *my knowledge*.

Firstly, it cannot be my *knowledges* as it's not a countable noun. If you want to refer to those known to you, the word is *[acquaintance](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ACQUAINTANCE)* or *known*.

> my acquaintances (derived from *acquaintance*) -example #3 there.

Comment: Right, let’s get acquainted!

Comment: @LucianSava sure ;) This is a good question.